# Sorting 2d array with 3 columns

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, compare

Sort array by column like what i want to do here is to sort my values on my last row and depending on that sorting the number on the other colums might change too in the same row

for example

`int[][] array= { {1, 5, 3},{2, 6, 4},{12, 10, 1},{30, 75, 1} };`

and the output should be

`{12, 10, 1}
{30, 75, 1}
{1, 5, 3}
{2, 6, 4}`

`System.out.println("Entre la cantidad de procesos que quiere correr: ");
                    int pros = scan.nextInt();

```
                int[][] myArr = new int[pros][3];

                for(int i=0; i< pros; i++){


                    System.out.println("CPU Burst proceso "+count+" :");
                     time2=scan.nextInt();

                     System.out.println("Arrival Time proceso "+count+" :"); 
                      arrt=scan.nextInt();


                      myArr[i][0]=count;
                      myArr[i][1]=time2;
                      myArr[i][2]=arrt;


                count++;
                }


                Arrays.sort(myArr, new Comparator<int[]>() {
                    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
                        return Integer.compare(o2[2], o1[2]);
                    }
                });



                System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArr)); `
```

Comment: Could you share what you have tried till now. You atleast need to come halfway , so that we can help you.

Comment: i found but i tried to implemented  but didnt work      myArr.sort(function (a, b) {  return a[2] - b[2]; });

Comment: could you please help me with the sorting algo that you want. based on you input and output, I cannot make out any logic

Comment: sort the last column of the array and that the values on the two columns go with the sorted column

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to compare the arrays by the third element.

We could use the following comparator:

```
(a1, a2) -> Integer.compare(a1[2], a2[2])
```

Which accepts two arrays as arguments and returns the result of `Integer.compare()` on their third elements.

For example:

```
int[][] array = {{1, 5, 3}, {2, 6, 4}, {12, 10, 1}, {30, 75, 1}};
Arrays.sort(array, (a1, a2) -> Integer.compare(a1[2], a2[2]));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Output:

```
[[12, 10, 1], [30, 75, 1], [1, 5, 3], [2, 6, 4]]
```

Comment: what are  the a1 or a2 ?

Comment: @IfrahimHernandez Just variables that represent the two `int[]` arrays we're comparing.

Comment: where do i get Comparator from

Comment: You need to create the comparator, as in the example. Try running it.

Answer (score -1):

Let's construct an auxiliary array whose length is the same as `array.length`:

```
int[] thirdColumnValues = new int[array.length];
```

Then we can copy the values of the third columns:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  thirdColumnValues[i] = array[i][2];
}
```

Then we can sort this auxiliary array:

```
Arrays.sort(thirdColumnValues);
```

Then we can store the sorted values back into the original array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i][2] = thirdColumnValues[i];
}
```

Comment: bu my array is 2d and sortable on the 3 column

Comment: Oops... Misunderstood your question!